# Is "Palestina" an Anachronism?

Tags: translation-philosophy, isaiah

Isaiah 14:31 says,

"**Howl, O gate; cry, O city; thou, whole Palestina, art dissolved: for there shall come from the north a smoke, and none shall be alone in his appointed times**."(KJV)

The Tanahk says,

**לאהֵילִ֚ילִי שַׁ֙עַר֙ זַֽעֲקִי־עִ֔יר נָמ֖וֹג פְּלֶ֣שֶׁת כֻּלֵּ֑ךְ כִּ֚י מִצָּפוֹן֙ עָשָׁ֣ן בָּ֔א וְאֵ֥ין בּוֹדֵ֖ד בְּמֽוֹעָדָֽיו:**

"*Howl [for the] gate, cry out [for the city]; Philistia has melted, all of you, for from the North smoke has come, and there is no straggler in his ranks*."

The King James Bible has translated "Philistia" to say "Palestina" 8 times, yet there is no record of "Palestine" being used before 500 BC, and Isaiah has been said to have prophesied from 740-700 BC.

Is "Palestina" an anachronism?

Comment: It would be useful if you quoted a source for the word not being used before 500 BC.

Comment: @Dottard The term "Palestine" first appeared in the 5th century BC when the ancient Greek historian Herodotus wrote of a "district of Syria, called Palaistinê" between Phoenicia and Egypt in The Histories.[6] Herodotus applied the term to both the coastal and the inland regions such as the Judean mountains and the Jordan Rift Valley.[7][8][9](Source Wikipedia)

Comment: @Dottard What is interesting is Philistia traditionally occupied the area now known as the Gaza Strip-which is south and west of "Palestine". Which begs another question, if "Palestina" is in effect the same as "Philistia", why is it located in a different geographic area?

Comment: All that says is that "Philistia" first appeared in a non-Biblical source in the 5th century.  I would argue that it was in use in the Bible well before that.

Comment: In modern Hebrew and Arabic, the pronunciation for Palestinian is Philistini.

Answer (score 4):

The Hebrew word פְלֶשֶׁת (Pelesheth) occurs 8 times in the Hebrew OT, Ex 15:14, Ps 60:8, 83:4, 7, 108:9, Isa 14:29, 31, Joel 3:4.  The KJV is uneven in its translation of the this word (variously Palestria or Philistia) which modern versions fairly uniformly render "Philistia".

The people of Philistia, namely, the Philistines, פְלִשְׁתִּי (Pelishti), are mentioned about 288 times in the Hebrew OT, Gen 10:14, 21;33, 34, 26:1, 8, 14, 15, 18, Ex 23:31, Josh 13:2, Judges 3:3, 3:31, 10:6, 7, 11, 13:1, 5, etc.

As can be seen from the above, these ancient peoples appear in the OT Hebrew record hundreds of times beginning with the Torah, notionally composed by Moses about 1450 BC.

Ellicott's comments in Ex 15:14 are useful:

> The inhabitants of Palestina are the Philistines, from whom the Holy
> Land derived the name which it still retains in most of the languages
> of modern Europe. The Hebrew word is Phĕlâsheth, of which the nearest
> English equivalent would be “Philistia.”

Similarly, Barnes says this:

> The inhabitants of Palestina - i. e. the country of the Philistines.
> They were the first who would expect an invasion, and the first whose
> district would have been invaded but for the faintheartedness of the
> Israelites.

The Pulpit commentary on Ex 15:14 is:

> The Hebrew is Phelasheth, which would perhaps be best translated
> "Philistia." (Compare Psalm 60:8; Psalm 87:4; Psalm 108:9.) The
> Philistine country was a strip of territory extending along the coast
> of the Mediterranean from a little below Gaze on the south, nearly to
> Mount Carmel on the north.

Thus, the name and usage is very ancient.

Comment: The KJV interpreters, along with the commentators seemed to have taken your view. What they don't explain is "What happened to the Philistines", as their lineage which was derived from the Greek, vs Semetic Canaanites disappeared, long before the Modern Day Palestinians arrived. Also, it doesn't explain the Philistines as being from the North, vs the Gaza strip.

Comment: @Tau - the ancient Philistines suposedly came from Crete and were originally sea-fairing peoples (Deuteronomy 2:23; Jeremiah 47:4).  The modern occupants of the Gaza strip are a mixture of Arabs and speak Arabic.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistines

Answer (score 0):

Actually **Palestine** derives from Philistia, a name the greek people gave to the land where there inhabited the **Philistines**, and they lived there since **12th century**, the territory being a small pocket of land on the south coast (between Tel Aviv and Gaza).

In the **2nd year of our era**, the romans called "Syria Palaestina" designating the south portion of the province of Syria and till the Arabia thence, and just after the World War I that it had some *status*.

But a dictionarized meaning of Palestine is (in modern times):

> Region bounded on the east by the Jordan River, on the **north** by the
> border between modern Israel and Lebanon, on the **west** by the
> Mediterranean Sea (including the coast of Gaza), and on the south by
> the Negev, with its southernmost extension reaching the Gulf of Aqaba.

A better visualization is the following:

[image]

*Source: Negotiation Affairs Department*

According to excavations made in 1996, more about the Royal Phistine Empire was brought to light, as we see in this paper:

PHILISTINE PTG̊Y, GREEK *ΠΕΝΤΑΓΑĨΑ ‘FIVE LANDS’ - פתגיה הפלשתית ו-*πενταγαĩα ("חמש הארצות") ביוונית
Philip C. Schmitz and פיליפ ס' שמיץ

Published By: Israel Exploration Society

Comment: I'm surprised the maps miss out the historic 1922 British Mandate. The areas known today as Israel - the West Bank and Gaza Strip - were designated as a single territorial unit called Palestine. In 1948 the British withdrew, Israel declared statehood and the first Arab-Israeli war broke out. In 1914 only 7.6% of the population were Jewish, the rest being Arabs. By 1931 it was 16.9% Jewish. At the last census before the creation of modern Israel, it was 29.9% Jewish.